# Python нужно очистить кортеж кортежей из модуля MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

я тут запарился с работой MySQL и решил сохранять туда базу бота.
Есть несколько колонок в таблице, но я использую только `vk_id`. Пытаюсь получить `SELECT vk_id FROM users` через метод `fetchall()` - он мне возвращает кортеж, в котором лишние скобки и запятые, то есть, кортеж кортежей. Как мне превратить это в список? По идее мне нужен чистый `id` без всего этого мусора. Вот пример вывода данных из БД:

```
((28683116,), (41268995,), (59767617,), (61421042,), (71254702,), (74850652,), (119684339,), (122795465,), (133647952,), (144829237,), (151724100,))
```

К слову, когда я пытаюсь превратить каждый элемент кортежа в список то он мне сообщает:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

А когда всё пытаюсь превратить список, он создаёт список кортежей:

```
[(28683116,), (41268995,), (59767617,), (61421042,), (71254702,), (74850652,), (119684339,), (122795465,), (133647952,), (144829237,), (151724100,)]
```

Конструкции `.join()` и `.replace()` не работают, так как они не могут работать с кортежем.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код для запроса данных, что выводите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу, что у вас примерно такой код запроса и получения списка:

```
items = cursor.execute("SELECT vk_id FROM users").fetchall()
print(items)  # ((28683116,), (41268995,), (59767617,), (61421042,), ...
```

Тогда, чтобы получить список только с `id`, без оберток-кортежей, нужно достать элемент из кортежа:

```
# Вариант 1
items = [vk_id[0] for vk_id in cursor.execute("SELECT vk_id FROM users")]

# Вариант 2
items = [vk_id for (vk_id,) in cursor.execute("SELECT vk_id FROM users")]

print(items)  # [28683116, 41268995, 59767617, 61421042, 71254702, ...
```

Comment: Хорошо ли запихивать `cursor.execute()` прямо в `list comprehension`?

Comment: @strawdog, вы правы

Comment: Спасибо, что вы дали наводку на верное решение, но всё же вы использовали `cursor.execute()`, а нужно было `cursor.fetchall()`. То есть верным решением было:
`items = [vk_id[0] for vk_id in mysql_cursor.fetchall()]`. На сколько я понял, `execute()` отправляет запрос базе, а `fetchone` или `fetchall` возвращает ответ.

Comment: @ДенисШляхтин, `execute()` отправляет запрос и возвращает ответ, ответ можно сразу обработать (тот же `cursor.execute().fetchall()`) либо у того же курсора отдельно запросить. Еще, `execute` должен быть итерируемым, т.е. он сам сможет в цикле вернуть записи. `fetchall()` же сначала получит все данные запроса, а после вернет список по результату